# Identity with start point set to a variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Students and I want to get the max id available in the list so that I can create a new list with other students starting with the id as being the latest value in the Students table. The explanation in code is written below:

```
declare @maxStudentId int
set @maxStudentId = (select max(StudentId) + 1 from Students)

create table #tempStudents
(
  tempId int identity(@maxStudentId, 1) primary key,
  maxGrade int
)
```

I have the next value after the maximum id value available in the Students table. For example, last id in Students is 100, so in `@maxStudentId`  I have the value 101.
For the new table, I want to set the starting id as 101, but I get an error when trying to set `identity(@maxStudentId, 1)` because the variable is not a number or an integer, + or -. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by dynamic sql, here is an example on how to do it

```
declare @SQL varchar(max)

declare @maxStudentId int
set @maxStudentId = (select max(StudentId) + 1 from Students)

set @SQL = 'create table #tempStudents ' +
           '( ' +
           'tempId int identity(' + convert(varchar, @maxStudentId) + ', 1) primary key, ' +
           'maxGrade int ' +
           ') '

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

the variable @SQL will contain something like

> create table #tempStudents (   tempId int identity(101, 1) primary key, maxGrade int )